# xfs formatted USB HDD getting mounted as yaffs filesystem with mount option '-t auto' in mdev automount.sh

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, mount, xfs

working on linux 3.12 kernel on custom board. I am trying to mount XFS formatted USB HDD on board, but on board kernel mounts HDD filesystem as yaffs.

My kernel supports both xfs and yaffs, i need both filesystem support in kernel. i can't remove any fs support.

mount option i use to mount drives is below. this is in mdev triggered automount.sh script.
mount command 'mount "/dev/$1" "${mpoint}/$1"'

please let me know, how can i make kernel to mount the USB as xfs filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an entry in `/etc/fstab` specifying the disk and the filesystem you want it mounted as.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/